# Find Orthonormal vectors that span V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

Define a vector-valued function $\eta: R^2 \to R^3$ by $\eta_1(x,y)=x^2$, $\eta _2(x,y)=y^2$ and $\eta_3(x,y)=(x-y)^2$, and let $\Omega_0=\eta((0,\infty)^2)$. Let V be the tangent space for $\Omega_0$ at (4,1,1). Find orthonormal vectors that span V.

This is a question from large sample theory that requires a lot of algebra. The book does not explain how to find orthonormal vectors for tangent spaces. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: First find the tangent space. Note that $\eta$ is approximated locally by $\eta(x+h) \approx \eta(x) + {\partial \eta(x) \over \partial x} h$.

Answer (score 0):

Find $(x,y)$ such that $\eta((x,y)) = (4,4,1)$ (there are two such points).

Compute ${\partial \eta ((x,y)) \over \partial z}$ and find an orthonormal basis for the range.

This can be done using the Gram Schmidt process.